# reading netstat of Ubuntu AWS EC2 instance

Tags: amazon-ec2, netstat, ddos

netstat:

```
ubuntu@ip-172-31-60-232:/$ netstat
Active Internet connections (w/o servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State
tcp        0    187 ip-172-31-60-232.:51044 unknown.prolexic.c:http ESTABLISHED
tcp        0    187 ip-172-31-60-232.:51045 unknown.prolexic.c:http ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 ip-172-31-60-232.ec:ssh rrcs-71-43-133-18:50725 ESTABLISHED
tcp        0    187 ip-172-31-60-232.:51048 unknown.prolexic.c:http ESTABLISHED
tcp        0    187 ip-172-31-60-232.:51046 unknown.prolexic.c:http ESTABLISHED
tcp        0    187 ip-172-31-60-232.:51047 unknown.prolexic.c:http ESTABLISHED
tcp        0    187 ip-172-31-60-232.:51050 unknown.prolexic.c:http ESTABLISHED
tcp        0    187 ip-172-31-60-232.:51049 unknown.prolexic.c:http ESTABLISHED
tcp        0    187 ip-172-31-60-232.:51043 unknown.prolexic.c:http ESTABLISHED
tcp6       0      0 ip-172-31-60-232.e:http 159.122.120.196-s:45931 CLOSE_WAIT
tcp6       0      0 ip-172-31-60-232.e:http 159.122.120.196-s:43103 CLOSE_WAIT
tcp6       0      0 ip-172-31-60-232.e:http 159.122.120.196-s:46224 CLOSE_WAIT
tcp6       0      0 ip-172-31-60-232.e:http 159.122.120.196-s:51975 CLOSE_WAIT
tcp6       0      0 ip-172-31-60-232.e:http 159.122.120.196-s:45529 CLOSE_WAIT
tcp6       0      0 ip-172-31-60-232.e:http 159.122.120.196-s:52326 CLOSE_WAIT
tcp6       0      0 ip-172-31-60-232.e:http 159.122.120.196-s:46529 CLOSE_WAIT
tcp6       0      0 ip-172-31-60-232.e:http 159.122.120.196-s:35851 CLOSE_WAIT
tcp6       0      0 ip-172-31-60-232.e:http 159.122.120.196-s:42878 CLOSE_WAIT
tcp6       0      0 ip-172-31-60-232.e:http 159.122.120.196-s:44822 CLOSE_WAIT
tcp6       0      0 ip-172-31-60-232.e:http 159.122.120.196-s:45080 CLOSE_WAIT
tcp6       0      0 ip-172-31-60-232.e:http 159.122.120.196-s:51681 CLOSE_WAIT
tcp6       0      0 ip-172-31-60-232.e:http 159.122.120.199-s:54884 CLOSE_WAIT
tcp6       0      0 ip-172-31-60-232.e:http 159.8.68.54-stati:53652 CLOSE_WAIT
tcp6       0      0 ip-172-31-60-232.e:http 159.122.120.196-s:51548 CLOSE_WAIT
tcp6       0      0 ip-172-31-60-232.e:http 159.8.68.54-stati:39783 CLOSE_WAIT
tcp6       0      0 ip-172-31-60-232.e:http 159.122.120.199-s:58173 CLOSE_WAIT
tcp6       0      0 ip-172-31-60-232.e:http 159.122.120.196-s:45439 CLOSE_WAIT
tcp6       0      0 ip-172-31-60-232.e:http 159.122.120.199-s:55093 CLOSE_WAIT
tcp6       0      0 ip-172-31-60-232.e:http 159.122.120.196-s:46086 CLOSE_WAIT
tcp6       0      0 ip-172-31-60-232.e:http 159.122.120.196-s:46085 CLOSE_WAIT
tcp6       0      0 ip-172-31-60-232.e:http 159.122.120.199-s:35563 CLOSE_WAIT
tcp6       0      0 ip-172-31-60-232.e:http 159.122.120.196-s:45901 CLOSE_WAIT
tcp6       0      0 ip-172-31-60-232.e:http 159.122.120.196-s:45727 CLOSE_WAIT
tcp6       0      0 ip-172-31-60-232.e:http 159.122.120.199-s:52116 CLOSE_WAIT
tcp6       0      0 ip-172-31-60-232.e:http 159.122.120.196-s:46065 CLOSE_WAIT
tcp6       0      0 ip-172-31-60-232.e:http 159.122.120.199-s:45937 CLOSE_WAIT
Active UNIX domain sockets (w/o servers)
Proto RefCnt Flags       Type       State         I-Node   Path
unix  2      [ ]         DGRAM                    8617     /var/spool/postfix/dev/log
unix  9      [ ]         DGRAM                    8615     /dev/log
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     101130   /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     101043   /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     9394
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     100999   /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     9448
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     101072   /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     9409
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     100993   /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
unix  2      [ ]         DGRAM                    8862
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     101134
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     101083
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     101054   /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     9450
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     8571
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     101000
unix  2      [ ]         DGRAM                    35035
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     9436
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     101112   /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     7997
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     9385
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     9438
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     9387
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     101049   /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     9442
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     9414
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     13189
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     9457
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     9453
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     9405
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     100996
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     9444
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     9396
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     8519
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     101117
unix  3      [ ]         DGRAM                    7633
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     101001   /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     9375
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     101111
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     9412
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     9430
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     101129
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     101045   /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     9432
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     7593     @/com/ubuntu/upstart
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     100997   /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     9415
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     100995   /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     100986
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     13190
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     101113
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     9374
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     101046
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     9371
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     101115
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     8639
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     9418
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     9370
unix  2      [ ]         DGRAM                    8619
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     9420
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     101108   /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     101071
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     101062   /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
unix  3      [ ]         DGRAM                    7634
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     101135   /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     101119
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     9377
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     9426
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     9424
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     101044
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     9445
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     8567
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     9378
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     100987   /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     101120   /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     9447
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     100994
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     9451
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     8572     /var/run/dbus/system_bus_socket
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     101084   /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     9381
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     9403
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     101048
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     9391
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     100998
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     101068   /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     9382
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     101078   /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     13197    /var/run/dbus/system_bus_socket
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     8008     @/com/ubuntu/upstart
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     100990
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     9411
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     9384
unix  2      [ ]         DGRAM                    9468
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     101109
unix  2      [ ]         DGRAM                    9463
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     9439
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     8640     /var/run/dbus/system_bus_socket
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     9406
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     100989   /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     9441
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     9400
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     8568
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     9456
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     9388
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     9408
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     101047   /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     101110   /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     9454
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     9390
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     9402
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     9397
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     9367
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     101107
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     9427
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     100988
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     101077
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     9429
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     101114   /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     101042
unix  2      [ ]         DGRAM                    12906
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     13196
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     9435
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     9433
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     101067
unix  2      [ ]         DGRAM                    9344
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     7582
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     101118   /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     9417
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     101053
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     8545     @/com/ubuntu/upstart
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     9421
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     9399
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     100991   /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     9393
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     101061
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     9423
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     100992
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     101116   /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     9368
ubuntu@ip-172-31-60-232:/$
```

> I believe someone is ddosing my server

I am thinking that the IP 159.122.120.196 is the culprit, but i am not entirely sure. my server has now turned back on. This is not my field of expertise so any guidance you can give me would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Don't let netstat resolve the addresses for you.  You have no way of knowing how to interpret those hostnames, which look like addresses, but you don't know if they are correct, and some reverse-DNS entries reverse the order of the octets.  Use `netstat -n` instead.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting malicious traffic from this same IP this evening, enough that it was spawing apache2 so fast my server kernel panicked. In my case, it was one of three IPs hitting xmlrpc.php on a Wordpress site multiple times per second. I dropped the traffic with iptables -- back in business.

If your question works out to "is 159.122.120.199 a bad actor IP address?", the answer appears to be yes.